# htmlentities in PHP - differences between local and live

Tags: php, html-entities

I edit certain pages of my website via textarea's and a common WYSIWYG editor. This editing frequently requires me to display HTML code by using `<pre>` tags.

Due to the nature of the textarea, I believe I'm required to use htmlentities in order to conserve HTML Entities such as `&lt;` (which is translated to <), so here is what I did:

```
<textarea name="resume" class="ckeditor"><?php echo htmlentities($e['resume']) ?></textarea>
```

This works great locally, my syntax highlighter works great in the pre tags, the textarea doesn't convert the HTML Entities when being edited.

So I try hosting this project, but on live there is a problem, all double quotes are being displayed as **\"** , there is a slash before all double quotes in my text.

Is this something I should take up with my host? I don't understand how locally this issue isn't happening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have Magic Quotes enabled on the live site.

Look at the documentation for `magic_quotes_gpc`: http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.magic-quotes-gpc

You can take it up with your host, but you can also disable it in a .htaccess file: http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.disabling.php

Comment: Thank you, I tried adding php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off at the end of my .htaccess file, but the site now gives me a Internal Server Error, so I guess my host will have to take a loo at it.